# How to catch exceptions inside threads

Tags: ruby, multithreading, exception

Why do threads behave differently from everything else in ruby?
I need to run some code in different threads and not having them vanishing into thin air each time something unexpected happens.

```
Thread.new do
    begin
        raise "Exception"
    rescue => exc
        print exc
    end
end
# Nothing happens
```

This code does nothing, for some reason. I tried to use `Thread::abort_on_exception = true` before that, doesn't change a thing.

So, how do I handle exceptions inside ruby threads correctly?

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me in IRB. I suspect the issue is that your program is terminating before the new thread finishes executing.

Comment: abort on exception does nothing because it does not raise the exception. if you truly want it to abort_on_exception either don't handle them inside the thread or re raise them after handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ajedi32 said, the problem is that the program is finishing before the thread has time to write "Exception".

There are two things to considerate here: Using `Thread::abort_on_exception = true` makes the program a lot easier to debug and avoids having nasty hidden bugs. The seconds one that I shouldn't be exiting the program without making sure every thread concluded correctly.
The code should instead be:

```
Thread::abort_on_exception = true 
my_thread = Thread.new do
    begin
        raise "Exception"
    rescue => exc
        print exc
    end
end

#Do some parallel stuff
my_thread.join
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to `join()` your thread. This code works:

```
Thread.new do
    begin
        raise "Exception"
    rescue => exc
        print exc
    end
end.join
```

Comment: Doesn't it mean that I have to wait for that code to finish before continuing? I need to have code running side by side ^^

Comment: Your program finished before thread. Instead of `join` (which is just "wait for thread") you can put some `sleep` at the end of the program and you would see that the thread is executed